# Plotting yearly/area comparison in ggplot in R through dodging

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following dataset showing when a person (denoted by variable id) synced data to the server in districts A and B. I already computed counts and percentages by district and year.

This is my summarized data:

```
df3 <- structure(list(district = c("A", "A", "B", "B"), year_sync = c(
  2019L,
  2020L, 2019L, 2020L
), ssum = c(32L, 32L, 33L, 33L), n = c(
  7L,
  25L, 25L, 8L
), percent = c(
  0.21875, 0.78125, 0.757575757575758,
  0.242424242424242
), label = c("21.88%", "78.12%", "75.76%", "24.24%")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), groups = structure(list(district = c(
  "A",
  "B"
), .rows = structure(list(1:2, 3:4), ptype = integer(0), class = c(
  "vctrs_list_of",
  "vctrs_vctr", "list"
))), row.names = 1:2, class = c(
  "tbl_df",
  "tbl", "data.frame"
), .drop = TRUE), class = c(
  "grouped_df",
  "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

I need to create a ggplot (like the one shown below).

[image]

This is my plotting code:

```
ggplot(df3, aes(y=ssum, x=factor(year_sync), fill=district)) +
      geom_bar(stat='identity',
               #color='black',
               position = position_dodge(width=0.8), width=0.8) +
      geom_text(aes(label = label),
                position = position_dodge(width=0.8),
                size = 3) +
      xlab ("Year")   +
      ylab ("Number of People")  +
      scale_fill_manual(values=c("aquamarine4", "bisque3")) +
      theme_minimal() +
      theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face = "bold"),
            plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face = "italic"))
```

However, the second part of the code gives me the following error: **Error in unique.default(x, nmax = nmax) : unique() applies only to vectors.**

Can anyone please help in telling what am I doing wrong as I am new to R.

Looking forward to solving this!

Thank you

Comment: I'm afraid I can't reproduce your error. There is no variable called `year` in your dataset `df3` (I replaced by year_sync). Also there is no variable `count` in `df3` (I replaced by ssum). I would recommend to restart R (Ctrl + Shift + F10), check whether you still get the error and if yes revise and edit your code.

Comment: I cannot test your code but I think your problem lies with the ` stat = "identity"  `part. Try running again with that part removed. Usually you use `stat = "identity" ` if you don't have a y variable and you just want the counts of your x variable.

Comment: Could you please include your data in the question using `dput(df)` to make it easier to copy and test out potential answers rather than the existing table view, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply replacing `year` with `year_sync`, `count`by `n` and mapping `n` on the `y` aes (instead of `ssum`) gives the wanted plot without any error messages:

```r
df3 <- structure(list(district = c("A", "A", "B", "B"), year_sync = c(
  2019L,
  2020L, 2019L, 2020L
), ssum = c(32L, 32L, 33L, 33L), n = c(
  7L,
  25L, 25L, 8L
), percent = c(
  0.21875, 0.78125, 0.757575757575758,
  0.242424242424242
), label = c("21.88%", "78.12%", "75.76%", "24.24%")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), groups = structure(list(district = c(
  "A",
  "B"
), .rows = structure(list(1:2, 3:4), ptype = integer(0), class = c(
  "vctrs_list_of",
  "vctrs_vctr", "list"
))), row.names = 1:2, class = c(
  "tbl_df",
  "tbl", "data.frame"
), .drop = TRUE), class = c(
  "grouped_df",
  "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df3, aes(y = n, x = factor(year_sync), fill = district)) +
  geom_bar(
    stat = "identity",
    color = "black",
    position = position_dodge(width = 0.8), width = 0.8
  ) +
  geom_text(aes(label = label, y = n),
    position = position_dodge(width = 0.8),
    size = 3, vjust = -1
  ) +
  xlab("Year") +
  ylab("Number of People") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("aquamarine4", "bisque3")) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face = "bold"),
    plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face = "italic")
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, stefan! I had also revised my code. Could you also tell me how can I add as a caption in this plot total number of people in district A and total number of people in district B (after filtering NAs), if possible? Thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: You are welcome. You can add a caption via `+ labs(caption = "....")`. If you want to put some computed values inside you can use something like `+ labs(caption = paste("Number of People in A:", n_a))`. Also, using labs you can also add a title, a subtitle, titles for the axes (via x = ..., y = ...) and legend (fill = .., i.e. you don't need xlab and ylab.

Comment: Thanks for getting back! However, the problem I am facing is how to save the number of people in each district as a variable (or however that is called in R) and then call it/refer to it in the caption? More concretely, the "n_a" in your comment - I have already calculated that but how do I refer to it? Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Hi @Rachita. As always there are several ways. Perhaps a bit advanced but try `n <- count(df3, district) %>% tibble::deframe() %>% as.list()` which gives you a list with elements A and B containing the number of people by district. `n$A` is the number of people in district A.